# How to omit redundant slugs in urls due to routes/layouts structure?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a project structure:

```
__layout.svelte <- requests header nav links in its load function
articles/
    __layout.svelte <- requests list of tags for left sidebar in its load function + provides column layout
    index.svelte <- list of all articles
    u[id].svelte <- list of articles made by specific user and some detailed user info
    [id].svelte <- detail page of specific article
about.svelte
contacts.svelte
```

So urls are like this:

```
/articles
/articles/u504
/articles/504
/about
/contacts
```

How can I omit `/articles` in urls, so they'll be like this:

```
/
/u504
/504
/about
/contacts
```

?

I've tried to play with `config.kit.vite.server.proxy` but it expectedly works only for server

Probably there is a way to manipulate with `manifest.js`?

Answer (score 0):

You could instead turn the `/articles/__layout.svelte` file into a component which you can put inside of `u[id].svelte` & `[id].svelte`.

You can a [slot](https://svelte.dev/docs#slot) to achieve this

Comment: I've tried, load() function works only in layouts or pages, not component(

Comment: You could put `load()` inside of `u[id].svelte` & `[id].svelte` instead of the component.

Comment: Want it be described once. In my case there really much more then `u[id].svelte` and `[id].svelte`

Comment: Extract it to a function and then call it in both.